# How to make an HTML element "accelerate" into position

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my site I have an element that stays in the upper corner, therefore following the user when he or she scrolls down. It's like [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6rfdyfk/). What I'd like to do instead is make it have a better following effect by staying put when the user scrolls and then accelerating back into it's fixed position. How would I do that?

```
#follow {
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    top: 70px;
}
```

---

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    // ???
});
```

Comment: since you are using jQuery, can use the `.animate()` property to animate the top position.

Comment: If u want, u may use `jQuery UI` [easing effect](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this, if you change to `position: absolute` and then use `.animate()`. Just need to make sure to use `.stop()` on each scroll so that if you scroll twice in quick succession it doesn't delay.

```
#follow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 70px;
}
```

---

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    $("#follow").stop();
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#follow").animate({"top":window_top+70}, 500);
});
```

Check out the fiddle to see if it's what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/f7gjvpof/3/

Answer (score 0):

if you have to set the `position` to `fixed`, i think it would need a complex animation simulating the moves (considering no css attribute changes when the position is fixed while scrolling).

but i think if you set the `position` to `absolute`, then you can set the element's `top` to the amount of `window.pageYOffset` and simply using `.animate` alongside some easing, you can really make the element accelerate while scrolling...